# Apache Flink KeyedProcessFunction onTimer method triggers Occasionally, not Always as per configurations

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have written a KeyedProcessFunction which runs based on specified key, the processFunction sets a timer which has been passed to it.
Ideally the onTimer function should be executed after the timer has reached the configured timed out

I have written the test case to test this, However the test cases works good on my local machine however the TestCases does not work well on my pipeline and the onTimer method is not triggered

I am sharing my KeyedProcessFunction and would be of great help someone can let me know if i am doing something incorrectly

Source Code

```
 @Override
    public void processElement(T value, KeyedProcessFunction<String, T, List<T>>.Context ctx, Collector<List<T>> out) {
        try {

            log.info("Realm {}  list size {} ", ctx.getCurrentKey(), currentSize.value());

            if (currentSize.value() == 0) {
                log.info("Registering timer for key {} current processing time {} new time for trigger {}", ctx.getCurrentKey(), ctx.timerService().currentProcessingTime(), ctx.timerService().currentProcessingTime() + timeout);
               // timerTime.update(System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout);
                timerTime.update(ctx.timerService().currentProcessingTime() + timeout);
                ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(timerTime.value());
            }

            mediatedRecords.add(value);
            currentSize.update(currentSize.value() + 1);
            if (currentSize.value() >= batchSize) {
                log.info("Realm {} size {} greater than equal to maxElements {}", ctx.getCurrentKey(), currentSize.value(), batchSize);
                Iterator<T> recordIterator = mediatedRecords.get().iterator();
                List<T> mediatedList = new ArrayList<>();
                recordIterator.forEachRemaining(record -> {
                    mediatedList.add(record);
                });
                out.collect(mediatedList);
                clearState();
                ctx.timerService().deleteProcessingTimeTimer(timerTime.value());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in process element ", e);
            out.collect(new ArrayList<>());
        }
    }

    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<List<T>> out) throws Exception {
        log.info("Current Processing Time :: {}", ctx.timerService().currentProcessingTime());
        log.info("Timer triggered for key {} elements {} batchSize {} ", ctx.getCurrentKey(), currentSize.value(), batchSize);
        Iterator<T> recordIterator = mediatedRecords.get().iterator();
        List<T> mediatedList = new ArrayList<>();
        recordIterator.forEachRemaining(record -> {
            mediatedList.add(record);
        });
        clearState();
        ctx.timerService().deleteProcessingTimeTimer(timerTime.value());
        out.collect(mediatedList);

        log.info("Values after clearing onTimeout for realm {}  {} {} ", ctx.getCurrentKey(), currentSize.value(), ctx.timerService().currentProcessingTime());
    }

    public void clearState() throws IOException {
        mediatedRecords.clear();
        currentSize.clear();
        currentSize.update(0L);
        timerTime.clear();
        timerTime.update(0L);
    }
```

Corresponding Test Case which is failing

```
@Test
    public void test_reEnrichment_mediation() throws Exception {

        this.execEnv = configureStreamExecutionEnvironment(jobInput.getMediationOutputDirConfig().
                getMediationOutputBucketPath());
        createTableEnvironment();
        reEnrichmentProcessorPipeline = new ReEnrichmentProcessorPipeline(execEnv, tableEnvironment
                , jobInput, new Properties(), new RunStatistics(), new Properties());

        //Create input json stream from text file
        DataStream<Usage> inputStream = execEnv.readFile(INPUT_STREAM, INPUT_FILE).map((line) ->
                GsonBuilder.getGson().fromJson(line, Usage.class)
        );

        //apply mediation to the input stream
        this.mediationOutputList = reEnrichmentProcessorPipeline.mediation(inputStream);

        //collect only 3 records, because expected records from mediation are 3 (2 from Input Stream and 1 extra from API Call)
        List<Row>outputList = this.mediationOutputList.get(0).getOutputStream().executeAndCollect(3);


        await().with()
                .pollInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .atMost(Duration.ofMinutes(2L))
                .untilAsserted(() -> {
                    System.out.println("Verifying Response :: ");
                    assertNotNull(this.mediationOutputList);
                    //only 1 mediationOutPut is generated, dataStream will have records
                    assertEquals(1,this.mediationOutputList.size());
                    assertEquals(3, outputList.size());
                    List<Object> ids = outputList.stream().map(s -> s.getFieldAs("id")).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    assertTrue(ids.contains("BILLABLE-USAGE-7ea0b297-f488-4025-a532-8e3e74e60cc8")); //id validation from API call
                    assertTrue(ids.contains("BILLABLE-USAGE-7ea0b297-f488-4025-a532-8e3e74e60bc8")); //id validation from Input Stream
                    assertTrue(ids.contains("BILLABLE-USAGE-7ea0b297-f488-4025-a532-8e3e74e60bc9")); // id validation from Input Stream
                });
    }
```

I have tried to change the processingTime to various parameters, SytemTime currentms to currentProcessing Time, they all work well on local but unable to debug on server what could be the  exact root cause

My Server Logs to indicate, that for 2 different keys processing Time is registered but only one timer is getting triggered instead of 2

```
  2024-01-05 09:08:07,146 [INFO] c.h.a.p.f.CountWithTimeoutFunction.processElement:49 [KeyedProcess -> Filter -> Map ...] - Realm org16291096  list size 0 
    2024-01-05 09:08:07,147 [INFO] c.h.a.p.f.CountWithTimeoutFunction.processElement:52 [KeyedProcess -> Filter -> Map ...] - Registering timer for key org16291096 current processing time 1704445687147 new time for trigger 1704445687152
 2024-01-05 09:08:07,179 [INFO] c.h.a.p.f.CountWithTimeoutFunction.onTimer:78 [KeyedProcess -> Filter -> Map ...] - Current Processing Time :: 1704445687179
    2024-01-05 09:08:07,179 [INFO] c.h.a.p.f.CountWithTimeoutFunction.onTimer:79 [KeyedProcess -> Filter -> Map ...] - Timer triggered for key org16291096 elements 1 batchSize 1000 
    2024-01-05 09:08:07,190 [INFO] c.h.a.p.f.CountWithTimeoutFunction.processElement:49 [KeyedProcess -> Filter -> Map ...] - Realm org16291097  list size 0 
    2024-01-05 09:08:07,191 [INFO] c.h.a.p.f.CountWithTimeoutFunction.processElement:52 [KeyedProcess -> Filter -> Map ...] - Registering timer for key org16291097 current processing time 1704445687191 new time for trigger 1704445687196
    2024-01-05 09:08:07,206 [INFO] c.h.a.p.f.CountWithTimeoutFunction.onTimer:89 [KeyedProcess -> Filter -> Map ...] - Values after clearing onTimeout for realm org16291096  0
```

As can be seen in the above logs, only one of the timer for Realm org16291096 has been triggered but not done for org16291097. Both have same type of record and no difference. But it doesnt work on server

Comment: Could it be that on the server the job is finished before the timer can be called? Flink doesn't care if there are pending processing time timers; when the job is done, it stops running.

Comment: What's the code for declaring your various state variables, and how are they being initialized? E.g. can `currentSize.value()` return null prior to it being set to something?